# CSS3 columns-property and the background-color

Tags: css

I've an `ul`-element and many `li`s. To the  is a background color assigned. Now I use CSS3 columns property and everything works fine, but the background color of my `ul` is only in the first column visible. What could be the reason?

Thanks!

```
<style>
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 170px;
    background: red;

    -webkit-column-count: auto;
    -moz-column-count: auto;
    column-count: auto;
    -webkit-column-width: @ul_level2_width;
    -moz-column-width: @ul_level2_width;
    column-width: 200px;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
  <li>Test 1</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z3ssn8b7/

Comment: Please create an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  example  and add the code to your question for us to be able to troubleshoot the issue

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is `column-count: auto;` If I set it so a fix count `2` everything works!